# Comparing parameters of two nonlinear models

Tags: t-test, nonlinear-regression

Suppose we use nonlinear regression (specifically the nls-package in R) for fitting separate models (e.g. same equation, different values of parameters) for two (or more for that matter) conditions in an experiment. One of the parameters has a clear real-world interpretation and we are thus interested in whether or not this parameter is different between the two models.

My understanding of the algorithm is that the parameter estimate is normally distributed, which leads me to believe that the difference in these parameters can be statistically tested with a t-test.

Can someone with a better understanding elaborate on why/why not this is appropriate? And i it is, what would be the degrees of freedom? And how do we account for the confounding effect of the other parameters in the model?

In practice, I would extract the estimate and std error from the model, simulate random variables from these and use the built in t-test function in R.

An example model would be a 3-parametric growth equation:

$y = L/(1 + exp(-k*(x-x0)))$

Edit: code supplied for example

The data is simulated with a random deviation and the parameters are tested by further simulating normally distributed data for each parameter within each model

```
rm(list=ls())

if (!require(nls2)){ install.packages(nls2) } 

par(mfrow=c(2,2))
par(mar=c(2.5,2.5,1.8,.5), family="serif", mgp = c(1.4, .4, 0),  font.lab=2)     

#Setting up the logistic equation as a function
LogiFun=function(x, L=10, k=2, x0=5)
{
  L/(1 + exp(-k*(x-x0)))
}

#Or simulate the data
#The possible x'es now go from 0-25, in intervals of 1 
x_vals=seq(from=0,to=36,by=2)

#now we make 3x the exes for three replicates
x=rep(x_vals,3)

#and then we simulate the y's for two different bacteria
#we also add some error to get some diversity
y1=LogiFun(x, L=9, k=1.5, x0=7 ) + rnorm(length(x),0,1); y1[y1<0] =0
y2=LogiFun(x, L=10, k=.5, x0=15) + rnorm(length(x),0,1); y2[y2<0] =0

#We then collect it in a data.frame
DAT=data.frame(x,y1,y2,repl=rep(1:3,each=length(x_vals) ) )

#and plot it
plot(  y1~x, bg=2, pch=20+repl, data=DAT)
points(y2~x, pch=21,bg=3)

#we then guess some parameteres
guess=list(L=c(10), k=c(1), x0=c(10))

#We then use these vaules to run the more accurate regression for both bacteria
nlsData1=nls2(y1 ~ L/(1 + exp(-k*(x-x0))), data = DAT,  start=guess)
summary(nlsData1)

nlsData2=nls2(y2 ~ L/(1 + exp(-k*(x-x0))), data = DAT,  start=guess)
summary(nlsData2)

#We plot the lines and are happy they fit
lines(LogiFun( x=seq(0,36,1), L = coef(nlsData1)[1], k = coef(nlsData1)[2], x0 = coef(nlsData1)[3] ) ~seq(0,36,1), col=2)
lines(LogiFun( x=seq(0,36,1), L = coef(nlsData2)[1], k = coef(nlsData2)[2], x0 = coef(nlsData2)[3] ) ~seq(0,36,1), col=3)

#extracting the coefficients
NLS1_coef=(summary(nlsData1))$coefficients
NLS2_coef=(summary(nlsData2))$coefficients

#we use k two pick the coeffecient of interest
#1 is L, 2 is k, 3 is x0 

for (k in 1:3)
{
  #making simulated data
  sim_model1=rnorm(length(x), mean = NLS1_coef[k,1], sd = sqrt(length(x))*NLS1_coef[k,2] )
  sim_model2=rnorm(length(x), mean = NLS2_coef[k,1], sd = sqrt(length(x))*NLS2_coef[k,2] )

  #T-testing simulated data
  pval = t.test(sim_model1 , sim_model2)$p.val

  #Showing the difference as normally distributed variables
  x_dist=seq(mean(c(NLS1_coef[k,1], NLS2_coef[k,1]))-10,mean(c(NLS1_coef[k,1], NLS2_coef[k,1]))+10,by=.1)
  plot(x_dist,  dnorm(x_dist, mean = NLS1_coef[k,1], sd = sqrt(length(x))*NLS1_coef[k,2]), col=2, type="l", xlab="x", ylab="prob", ylim=c(0,.5) )
  lines(x_dist, dnorm(x_dist, mean = NLS2_coef[k,1], sd = sqrt(length(x))*NLS2_coef[k,2]), col=3 )
  title(main = paste(rownames(NLS1_coef)[k], ", P=",signif(pval, 5) ) )
}
```

Comment: It depends very much on the model.  Could you provide details of the two models?

Comment: Sure, will update question

Comment: @whuber, did you have any suggestions..?

Comment: Yes: you need to complete your specification of the situation.  That would include (a) a description of the data and (b) an indication of how the values of $y$ might deviate from the modeled values.  The latter is especially important in determining whether estimates of the parameters have approximately Normal distributions.

Comment: Any thoughts on the models?